# Print jobs to USB printer sit in spooler and don't print

Tags: usb, printing, brother

I can send jobs to my print spooler, but they just sit there.

From my CUPS browser page http://localhost:631/printers/Brother_HL-L2350DW_series

```
Description:    Brother HL-L2350DW series
Location:   
Driver: Brother HL-L2350DW series, driverless, cups-filters 1.21.3 (grayscale, 2-sided printing)
Connection: dnssd://Brother%20HL-L2350DW%20series._ipp._tcp.local/?uuid=e3248000-80ce-11db-8000-d46a6a59f9a6
Defaults:   job-sheets=none, none media=na_letter_8.5x11in sides=two-sided-long-edge
```

Jobs just sit in the queue and the status remains "Processing"

I restarted by printer and the panel says "Sleeping" which is normal.

My printer is connected via a USB cable:

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 003 Device 011: ID 04f9:009e Brother Industries, Ltd
```

What else can I do to diagnose this?  I just made a fresh install of 18.04.

Comment: I notice that your printer says it is paused - In the web control panel, can you select the printer, then choose 'maintenance' in the printer's page, and then 'Resume Printer'?

Comment: I factory-reset the IP connection, then re-connected.  Now it's: "(Processing, Accepting Jobs, Not Shared, Server Default)"  There is a test page sitting in the queue for 5 minutes "processing". Giving up.